# How do I supply my password to Bazaar so it can fetch my code from my remote server?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I have a codebase on a remote Linux server (in my private home directory). I am traveling and my internet connection is spotty, so I'd like to download the code locally, work on it, and then push changes to the server. Since I'm already managing the codebase with Bazaar, seems like that's the logical tool to use for this task as well. I downloaded Bazaar for Windows, and tried creating a branch, but can't figure out what location to enter in the "From" field. My first guess was to do it the way I do with `scp`, where I enter:

```
username@host.com/subfolder-with-code
```

But that didn't work. Also, where do I enter my password?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just needed to add the protocol to that your url:

```
bzr branch bzr+ssh://username@host.com/subfolder-with-code
```

should do the trick.

See `bzr help urlspec` for more info.